# How do I get the result of an RetryTemplate.execute in Spring java?

Tags: java, spring

I'm fairly new to java and spring and I'm trying to figure out how to receive the result of an `RetryTemplate.execute` command. I would like to return a `false` if the execute command fails, and a `true` if it succeeds. I've tried assigning the values of res in the `execute` function but all i got was an error saying that `java: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`

heres my code:

```
private boolean forward(String message) {
        boolean res;
        retryTemplate.execute(retryCallback -> {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            ResponseEntity<String> responses = restTemplate.postForEntity(kafkaForwarderSetting.getUrlEndpoint(),
                    new HttpEntity<>(message, headers), String.class);

            if (responses.getStatusCodeValue() > 300) {
                throw new ForwarderException("Error occurred while forwarding message to endpoint!",
                        retryCallback.getLastThrowable());
            }
            // SET res to true
            return true;
        }, recoveryCallback -> {

            // SET res to false
            return false;
        });

        return res;
    }
```

From the documentation, it seems that `execute` returns `<T, E extends Throwable>` on the `retryTemplate` and whenever I return the value (such as the `return true;` on line 12), I should be able to access that very value.

However I don't know how to get it and printing out the `retryTemplate` itself gives me `org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate@5d65976d`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error

```
local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
```

means that in Java, you cannot change the reference of a variable declared outside of a lambda inside of it.

To circumvent this, you can use `MutableBoolean` from the [Apache Commons Lang 3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) library.

First, include the library into your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, import `MutableBoolean` into your class using

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableBoolean;
```

Now, replace

```
boolean res;
```

with

```
final MutableBoolean res = new MutableBoolean();
```

The `final` is optional, but good practice.

To set the value, write

```
res.setValue(true);
```

or

```
res.setValue(false);
```

You can use one of the three following methods to retrive the value after your lambda:

```
boolean isFalse = res.isFalse();
boolean isTrue = res.isTrue();
Boolean value = res.getValue();
```

Note that `res.getValue()` will give you a boxed `Boolean`, while the other two methods give you an unboxed `boolean`. These are great for `if`-statements.

I hope this helps.